# How to access a url if it has accented characters in it

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, urllib

So I am working on a script that will automatically download and write data from a web service that delivers information in json format.  They are Canadian political parties and as such, accented characters pop up quite often.

For instance, to access the data for candidates representing the party "Bloc Québécois", I need to access this url:

https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1000&party_name=Bloc%20Qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois

Unfortunately, the simple solution of replacing the é's with e's does not work.

so my script looks like this"

```
import urllib

#party_name_list = ["Conservative", "Liberal", "NDP", "Green%20Party", "Bloc%20Québécois", "Forces%20et%20Démocratie", "Libertarian", "Christian%20Heritage"]
party_name_list = ["Bloc%20Québécois"]

for party_name in party_name_list:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(r"https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1000&party_name={}".format(party_name)) as url:
        with open(r"F:\electoral_map\20150914\candidates\candidates_{0}.json".format(party_name), "wb+") as f:
            f.write(url.read())
    print("finished {0}".format(party_name))
print("all done")
```

I understand that this has something to do with utf-8 encoding, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it and the other links I find here and on other websites are not helping.

I tried adding a .encode('utf-8') in the urlopen call like this:

```
import urllib

#party_name_list = ["Conservative", "Liberal", "NDP", "Green%20Party", "Bloc%20Québécois", "Forces%20et%20Démocratie", "Libertarian", "Christian%20Heritage"]
party_name_list = ["Bloc%20Québécois"]

for party_name in party_name_list:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(r"https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1000&party_name={}".format(party_name.encode(utf-8))) as url:
        with open(r"F:\electoral_map\20150914\candidates\candidates_{0}.json".format(party_name), "wb+") as f:
            f.write(url.read())
    print("finished {0}".format(party_name))
print("all done")
```

But that just makes the file return empty because it is now calling the url:

https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1000&party_name=b'Bloc%20Qu\xc3\xa9b\xc3\xa9cois'

Can someone please help me to understand how to make sense of this mess?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it but I think that it is not the most elegant solution, and I don't really fully understand it, to be honest.  Maybe someone here can explain it better, but using urllib.parse.unquote_plus() helped me out:

```
import urllib

party_name_list = ["Conservative", "Liberal", "NDP", "Green Party", "Bloc Québécois", "Forces et Démocratie", "Libertarian", "Christian Heritage"]

for party_name in party_name_list:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(r"https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1000&party_name={}".format(urllib.parse.quote_plus(party_name))) as url:
        with open(r"F:\electoral_map\20150914\candidates\candidates_{0}.json".format(party_name), "wb+") as f:
            f.write(url.read())
    print("finished {0}".format(party_name))
print("all done")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing apples and oranges, sort of.  The bytes used to represent a string like "Québécois" or "" depend on the character set and encoding.  *Typically,* a modern web site will use UTF-8 in the URL, but there is no guarantee.

In UTF-8 (and basically every other modern encoding) the space is represented by one byte, 0x20 -- this is what you see URL-encoded as `%20`.  The character *é* ([U+00E9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm)) is encoded using the byte sequence 0xC3 0xA9 (though notice that it could equivalently be decomposed into 0x65 0xCC 0x81!) and so again, applying URL encoding to that yields `%C3%A9`.

But anyway, like you discovered, `urllib` takes care of this nicely and transparently for you, so you don't really need to understand the above.  I would regard the code you came up in with in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32576641/874188) as correct and idiomatic.

Proper understanding in the general case would require knowledge of at least the most common different [character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) as well as [Unicode normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).